# localStorage and jQuery Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage

This script below displays the characters remaining (allowable) in a form element (textarea). I want to use local storage to keep the text entered in the textarea until I submit the form.

I am trying to use localStorage so that when I come back to the page - the characters remaining (var text_remaining) doesnt show the full 2000 characters and should only show the characters left...(var text_remaining) ???

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
var char_th = 2000;
    var text_max = 2000;

    $('#textarea_feedback').html(char_th + ' characters remaining');
    //$('#textarea_feedback').html(text_max + ' characters remaining');

    $('#comments').keyup(function() {
            var text_length = $('#comments').val().length;
            var text_remaining = text_max - text_length;



            $('#textarea_feedback').html(text_remaining + ' characters remaining');
    });
});

</script>
```

This is what I ended up using
SOLVED - WORKS

```
 <script>

$(document).ready(function() {
    var text_max = 2000;

$('#comments').keyup(function() {
        var text_length = $('#comments').val().length;

        var text_remaining = text_max - text_length;
        localStorage.setItem("text", $('#comments').val());

        $('#textarea_feedback').html(text_remaining + ' characters remaining');
});


 $('#textarea_feedback').html(text_max + ' characters remaining');
 var text = localStorage.getItem("text");

 $('#comments').val(text);
 $('#comments').keyup();

});

</script>
```

Comment: The code you have posted does not seem to use `localStorage` at all.

Comment: should say I "want ot use" localStorage

Comment: Here is a jsFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/timur/47a7A/ - Trying to use localStorage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var char_th = 2000;
  var text_max = 2000;
  $('#comments').keyup(function() {
    var text_length = $('#comments').val().length;

    var text_remaining = text_max - text_length;
    localStorage.setItem("text", $('#comments').val());

    $('#textarea_feedback').html(text_remaining + ' characters remaining');
  });
  $('#textarea_feedback').html(char_th + ' characters remaining');
  var text = localStorage.getItem("text");

  $('#comments').val(text);
  $('#comments').keyup();


});
```

Comment: I removed the var char_th - dont think i need it - Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here you go!

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
    var char_th = 2000;
    var text_max = 2000;

    $('#textarea_feedback').html(char_th + ' characters remaining');
    localStorage.setItem("charrem", char_th");

    $('#comments').keyup(function() {
            var text_length = $('#comments').val().length;
            //var text_remaining = text_max - text_length;
            var text_remaining = localStorage.getItem("charrem");


            $('#textarea_feedback').html(text_remaining + ' characters remaining');
    });
});

</script>
```

Comment: this did not work - still shows 2000 with text already in the textarea

Comment: Thanks to @The Dark Knight

Answer (score 0):

You will want to clean this up a bit but I think something like this is what you are after:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var text_max = 99;
var remaining = (localStorage.getItem('remaining') > 0) ? localStorage.getItem('remaining') : text_max;
localStorage.setItem('remaining', remaining);
$('#textarea').val(localStorage.getItem('txtText'));
$('#textarea_feedback').html(remaining + ' characters remaining');

$('#textarea').keyup(function() {
    var text_length = $('#textarea').val().length;
    var text_remaining = text_max - text_length;
    localStorage.setItem('remaining', text_remaining);
    localStorage.setItem('txtText', $('#textarea').val());
    $('#textarea_feedback').html(text_remaining + ' characters remaining');
});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

You will have to continuously set and get the item from local storage and instead  grab the remaining value from `localstorage` **not** `text_remaining` variable .

**Example:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var char_th = 2000;
    var text_max = 2000;


//First check local storage for any data
    var remaining = localStorage.getItem('remainder');

    if(remaining == null || remaining == undifined){

        //use 2000 if nothing has been typed 
    $('#textarea_feedback').html(char_th + ' characters remaining');

}else{

//use localstorage if value exists

$('#textarea_feedback').html(remaining + ' characters remaining');

}





    $('#comments').keyup(function() {
            var text_length = $('#comments').val().length;
            var text_remaining = text_max - text_length;

            //Here we add two lines to continuously put/pull from local storage

            var setremaining = localStorage.setItem('remainder' text_remaining);

            var remaining = localStorage.getItem('remainder');

            $('#textarea_feedback').html(remaining + ' characters remaining');
    });
});
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I've made a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/VincentWilkie/2et1zzu0/) where the text is saved in local storage and `text_max` is set to the maxlength of the textarea. (a bit of adaptability)

```js
(function () {
    var text_max = $('textarea').attr('maxlength');

    if (!localStorage['text']) { localStorage['text'] = ""; }

    $('textarea').val(localStorage['text']);

    var char_th = text_max - localStorage['text'].length;

    $('p').html(char_th + ' characters remaining');

    $('textarea').keyup(function (event) {
        var text_length = this.value.length;
        var text_remaining = text_max - text_length;
        $('p').html(text_remaining + ' characters remaining');
        localStorage['text'] = this.value;
    });
})();
```

```html
<textarea cols="30" rows="10" maxlength="2000"></textarea>

<p></p>
```